# C#.NET Winform - Get Current Chrome URL takes a long time

Tags: c#, winforms, google-chrome

From below code I can get current Chrome URL but it takes time. Sometime it takes more than 2 Min and sometime it did not return any value.

Please guide me to solve this problem.

```
public string GetActiveTabUrl_Google_Chrome()
{ 
                
    Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

    if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
        return null;

    foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
    {
        // the chrome process must have a window 
        if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 


        AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
        var SearchBar = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"));
        if (SearchBar != null)
        {                    
            return (string)SearchBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePatternIdentifiers.ValueProperty);

        }
    }
}
```

I've googled a lot but did not get the exact solution. I've tried multiple PC but found the same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The key to reducing the time required is to use more conditions and also not to use the `NameProperty`, which seems to take a lot of time. Using the following code, I was able to get the URL in about 4 seconds.

```
static string GetURL()
{
    Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

    foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome)
    {
        if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            continue;

        AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);

        if (root == null)
            return null;

        Condition conditions = new AndCondition( // using multiple conditions which seems to be faster and descibe URL bar
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, chrome.Id),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsControlElementProperty, true),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsContentElementProperty, true),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));

        AutomationElement urlbar = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, conditions);
        return (string)urlbar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePatternIdentifiers.ValueProperty);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Getting chrome URL using c#]

Comment: Test it, but did not get any url.

Comment: What version of chrome do you have?

Comment: Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I have the same version and it works for me. Do you have any special chrome settings?

Comment: No, Default setting.

Comment: I tried your code with `Stopwatch` counter and measured above 10 seconds on average. NOTE: I had to edit your code, I added `return null` at the end of the function so it would compile.

Comment: Your code and my one is almost same. So where is the problem ?
Note : I've tried another PC and got same delay.